# Spree 2.3 - disabling stock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm using Rails 4.1.6 and Spree 2.3.1.

Using the default stock functionality is not relevant for the webshop im trying to build.

How do i disable it?

Some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Spree config variable to disable stock:

```
Spree::Config[:track_inventory_levels] = false
```

More docs here:
http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/inventory.html